# How to filter two values for given single search?

Tags: asp.net, sql, search, intentfilter

How to show two records for given single search?

UI page contains millions of records.I need to show only two records instead of giving
single search.
using OR SEARCH or whatever use.I want to show two records.
And how can i give two values in single text box?

Comment: okay, so if user put in `deer tiger elephant`, the filter condition would be `WHERE animal="deer" AND animal="tiger" AND animal="elephant"` and so on so forth?

Comment: Thanks. If each string contains more then two words mean,what to do?

Comment: we would need to see some sample records that you need filter, a mock up if you can,

Comment: Consider a UI page that will contains millions of records(Grid or List) like Organization name,Email,Phone,.... i want to filter two organization name in single search, instead of i given two organization name in search text-box.

Answer (score 1):

That dependa on you only, you can make use of some special charater to break two string like : or | so that you allow to etner two string like `"abc|5678"` than in back end you break this string in two string `string1 = abc and string2=5678`

Comment: Thanks sir.But i want simple layout for search.for example, consider a simple UI page,it contains millions of records and bottom area were contain search button with single text box.How can i give two values in single text-box?

Comment: @aravind - have you seen google search you can do same thing break word by space.........than do search ...........

Comment: but string values contain more then two words, i want search two organization name.is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Two values in single text box:

```
txt.Text = "value1" + "value2";
```

Comment: Thanks,But i want to simple layout.

Comment: Explain in which layout u want ?

Comment: Thanks, Consider a simple UI page,it contains millions of records like Organization name,Email,phone,Address that will appearing in Grid view or any else.  And top of the grid contains search button with single text box. I want to filter two organization name in single search.What can i do?